# A simple stemming algorithm with String for input

Tags: java, algorithm, stemming, porter-stemmer

I've been looking at word stemming algorithms such as the porter algorithm, but everything I've found so far has dealt with files as input.

Are there any existing algorithms which would let me simply pass the stemmer a string, and have it return the stemmed string?

Something like:

```
String toBeStemmed = "The man worked tirelessly";
Stemmer s = new Stemmer();

String stemmed = s.stem(toBeStemmed);
```

Comment: A great site about porter-stemmer is http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/

Answer (score 0):

The algorithms themselves don't take files. The code probably takes the file and reads it in as a series of Strings, which are fed to the algorithm. You just need to look at the part of the code that reads the Strings in from the file, and pass the Strings in yourself in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `toBeStemmed` is a sentence, that you want to tokenize first. Then you would stem the individual tokens/words, like 'worked' or 'tirelessly'.

Here's fine morphological analyzer I use as a stemmer in some of my projects.

stemmer JAR: https://code.google.com/p/hunglish-webapp/source/browse/trunk/#trunk%2Flib%2Fnet%2Fsf%2Fjhunlang%2Fjmorph%2F1.0
stemmer source: https://code.google.com/p/j-morph/source/checkout
language resource files: https://code.google.com/p/hunglish-webapp/source/browse/trunk/#trunk%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fresources%2Fresources-lang%2Fjmorph
How I use it with Lucene: https://code.google.com/p/hunglish-webapp/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/hu/mokk/hunglish/jmorph/
properties file: https://code.google.com/p/hunglish-webapp/source/browse/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/stemmer.properties

Example usage:

```
import net.sf.jhunlang.jmorph.lemma.Lemma;
import net.sf.jhunlang.jmorph.lemma.Lemmatizer;
import net.sf.jhunlang.jmorph.analysis.Analyser;
import net.sf.jhunlang.jmorph.analysis.AnalyserContext;
import net.sf.jhunlang.jmorph.analysis.AnalyserControl;
import net.sf.jhunlang.jmorph.factory.Definition;
import net.sf.jhunlang.jmorph.factory.JMorphFactory;
import net.sf.jhunlang.jmorph.parser.ParseException;
import net.sf.jhunlang.jmorph.sample.AnalyserConfig;
import net.sf.jhunlang.jmorph.sword.parser.EnglishAffixReader;
import net.sf.jhunlang.jmorph.sword.parser.EnglishReader;
import net.sf.jhunlang.jmorph.sword.parser.SwordAffixReader;
import net.sf.jhunlang.jmorph.sword.parser.SwordReader;

AnalyserConfig acEn = new AnalyserConfig();
//TODO: set path to the English affix file
String enAff = "src/main/resources/resources-lang/jmorph/en.aff"; 
Definition affixDef = acEn.createDefinition(enAff, "utf-8", EnglishAffixReader.class);
//TODO set path to the English dict file
String enDic = "src/main/resources/resources-lang/jmorph/en.dic"; 
Definition dicDef = acEn.createDefinition(enDic, "utf-8", EnglishReader.class);
int enRecursionDepth = 3;
acEn.setRecursionDepth(affixDef, enRecursionDepth);
JMorphFactory jf = new JMorphFactory();
Analyser enAnalyser = jf.build(new Definition[] { affixDef, dicDef });
AnalyserControl acEn = new AnalyserControl(AnalyserControl.ALL_COMPOUNDS);
AnalyserContext analyserContextEn = new AnalyserContext(acEn);
boolean enStripDerivates = true;
Lemmatizer enLemmatizer = new net.sf.jhunlang.jmorph.lemma.LemmatizerImpl(enAnalyser, enStripDerivates, analyserContextEn);


//After somewhat complex initializing, here we go
List<Lemma> lemmas = enLemmatizer.lemmatize("worked");
for (Lemma lemma : lemmas) {
    System.out.println(lemma.getWord());
}
```